# MenuItem - change colour, text and set a divider

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a problem with an inflated menu. What I want is to change the background colou, the text of the items and to set a divider between the items. I read a lot of the comments and tried different ways (hacks/selectors) but nothing has worked so far. 
Here is the menu's calling:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    Menu currentActionViewMenu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

In the style I tried inserting these items

```
<item name="android:background">@color/gray_600</item>
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/gray_400</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@color/black_90</item>
```

but the result still is far from the desired. Thanks!

Comment: i have answered your question , if still you are still facing problem then show your style.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.4dp</item>

</style>
```

as shown above `android:itemBackground` change the item background color , `android:dividerHeight` add a divider and `android:textColor` change the text color

Comment: Well, almost :) I'd want the whole background to be changed (without limiting the text area on this way). May you check it? As soon as I have 15 reputation, you have a plus from me.

Comment: Lolz thank u , for me this changed whole background , may be you want to check all methods related to color and background by using auto complete feature of android studio :)

Comment: Hm, oki, thank you, will follow the advice. Will get back as soon as I find wher the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poN3k.png)
Thank you,Manish, this is the result out of your suggestion.